# Creating array from file and formatting with Powershell

Tags: php, arrays, powershell, format

**What I'm trying to do:** Get User logon statistics with Powershell using get-winevent (ID: 4624).  If you know of a better way, I'm not opposed to other suggestions.  I've gotten it to work, but it's not formatted how I need it.  This is the Powershell Code I have (I'm a Powershell novice, but some stuff is similar to PHP, which I'm comfortable with):

```
$LogonIDs = "4624"
$computers = get-content "c:\computers.txt"
foreach($pc in $computers) {
    if(test-connection $pc -count 1 -quiet) {
        write-host "Acquiring information for $pc"
        foreach ($item in $LogonIDs) {
            (Get-WinEvent -computername $pc -max 2000 -FilterHashtable @{Logname='security';Id=$item} `
                | Select TimeCreated,Message `
                | fl * `
                | findstr /G:c:\search.lst) `
                -replace "^[\s]+","" `
                -replace "[\s]+"," " `
                | out-file -append "c:\scripts\winevent\$LogonIDs.txt" 
        }
    }
    else {
        write-host "Couldn't ping $pc"
    }
}
```

search.lst has the following information:

```
TimeCreated
Account Name:
Logon Type:
Logon GUID:
Logon Type:
Process Name:
```

The script will export something like this:

```
TimeCreated : 5/2/2013 7:19:39 AM
Account Name: COMPUTERNAME$
Logon Type: 2
Account Name: [USERNAME]
Logon GUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe
TimeCreated : 5/2/2013 7:19:39 AM
Account Name: COMPUTERNAME$
Logon Type: 2
Account Name: [USERNAME]
Logon GUID: {AKEJ38DJ-3K45-3LKD-3LKD-DKEJ3787DJJ3}
Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe
TimeCreated : 5/2/2013 6:50:42 AM
Account Name: -
Logon Type: 3
Account Name: COMPUTERNAME$
Logon GUID: {K458D890-3KJ8-DK3J-DK39-3LDJK23LD909}
Process Name: -
TimeCreated : 5/2/2013 6:27:22 AM
Account Name: COMPUTERNAME$
Logon Type: 5
Account Name: SYSTEM
Logon GUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\services.exe
```

This script exports everything great, but I am terrible at formatting and parsing unneeded information with Powershell.  I can format everything I need with PHP, but if someone can help me weed out specific information with Powershell, that'd be outstanding.

```
1) Explode at TimeCreated to create array
2) If Logon Type = 2, proceed, else skip to next value;
3) If Process Name contains winlogon.exe, proceed, else skip to next value;
4) If GUID = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}, skip to next value;
5) If GUID != {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}, Account Name[0] = computername, Account Name[1] = Username, build new array with this information
```

Here's the PHP I used to do this:

```
$file = "4624.txt";
$file_explode = explode("TimeCreated",$file);
while(list($k,$v) = each($file_explode)) {
    $account_name = "";
    $time = "";
    if(preg_match("/Logon Type\:[\s]+2/msU",$v)) {
        if(preg_match("/winlogon\.exe/msU",$v)) {
            if(strstr($v,"{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}")) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                preg_match("/[\s]+\:[\s]+(.*)$/msU",$v,$time);
                preg_match_all("/Account Name\:[\s]+(.*)$/msU",$v,$account_name);
                $new_arr[] = array(
                    "time" => $time[1],
                    "computer_name" => $account_name[1][0],
                    "user" => $account_name[1][1]
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I can't use that PHP (which I just found out), is that I can't post the 4624.txt to my web server because it contains PII (Personally Identifable Information).  If anyone can help me out, I would be forever in your debt ;]

-Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I approach this sort of problem by creating a custom object in PowerShell where there is a property for every piece of data I want. Once you have an object it is much easier to use Sort-Object, Group-Object, Format-Object to manipulate the data.

```
 $LogonIDs = 4624
 $IgnoreLogonGuid = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'

 function Parse-LogonID4624Event
 {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [psobject[]]
        $EventLogEntry
    )

    Process {
        foreach ($ev in $EventLogEntry)
        {
            $TimeCreated = [DateTime]::Parse($ev.TimeCreated)

            $AccountName = 'not found'
            if ($ev.Message -match '(?ims)New Logon:.*?Account Name:\s*(\S+)')
            {
                $AccountName =  $matches[1]
            }

            $LogonGuid = 'not found'
            if ($ev.Message -match '(?ims)^\s+Logon GUID:\s*(\S+)')
            {
                $LogonGuid =  $matches[1]
            }

            $obj = [pscustomobject] @{
                    TimeCreated = $TimeCreated
                    AccountName = $AccountName
                    LogonGuid = $LogonGuid
                    Message = $ev.Message
            }
            $obj
        }
    }
 }

 Get-WinEvent -max 20 -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=$LogonIDs} | 
     Parse-LogonID4624Event |
     Where LogonGuid -ne $IgnoreLogonGuid
```

This implementation doesn't grab all the fields you need but I think you can see easily how to rinse & repeat for the other fields you need.  Note that this implementation uses PowerShell v3 specific features.  If you need this on v2 let me know.  It should require just a few tweaks.